# Unity3D : Unable to change TextMesh in instantiated object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I instantiate an object and change the text mesh inside it using the below code.

```
GameObject folder = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab,<newLocation>,Quaternion.identity);
folder.name = "Folder1";
TextMesh content = GameObject.Find("Folder1").transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(3).
                     gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
content.text = "New Content";
```

But, when I run the scene, the text mesh still has the value from the prefab and is not updated. Has anyone faced a similar issue or any idea on how to resolve it?

Comment: When you debug your code, are content.text set to "New Content" value after last line execution?

Comment: It is after the last line of the function in which this is being set, but it changes to "old content" when it comes out of it

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the item gets updated properly but then when you create new ones, it does not work anymore.

I would think your problem is that you are naming them with the same name "Folder1". Then you are looking for an object called Folder1 and the first one is returned.

```
GameObject folder = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab,<newLocation>,Quaternion.identity);
folder.name = "Folder1";
TextMesh content = folder.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(3).
                     gameObject.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
content.text = "New Content";
```

this could fix your problem. Notice this is no longer looking for an item but using the reference from the new object.

Comment: I am using folder1 for example here, in my code, I increment the count with each created object.

Comment: Even when you use the reference directly like I suggest, do you still get the issue?

Comment: Try to use a Debug.Break() so that you can inspect the state of your text mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the right object? Your `GetChild`'s are a bit worrying. Maybe you can try giving your object a tag and searching for that instead. 
So, you set the tag of the gameobject that has your textmesh to `HasTextMesh` and then in your code do:

```
GameObject folder = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab,<newLocation>,Quaternion.identity);
TextMesh content = GameObject.FindWithTag("HasTextMesh").GetComponent<TextMesh>();
content.text = "New Content";
```

Comment: The scene when it first loads works fine, so I am sure the `GetChild`'s are proper. Only when I reload the scene with different content on the run, I am facing this issue

Comment: How are you calling this code when it doesn't work? Do you have your code in a method that you call? Is it in a start function?

Comment: this code is within a function which is called from the update method.

Comment: And you are sure it's finding the correct thing? Could you maybe try just disabling the entire gameobject with your code? To see if it disappears?